# NuxtServerError Cannot find module './headerMain.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=24ddd206&lang=scss&scoped=true&'

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image: браузер][[image: ![]`

> `почему возникает ошибка?headerMain используется в index.vue.
>    до этого смог решить только созданием нового проекта и копированием туда старых компонентов

```js
<script>
import promo from "~/components/header/promo.vue";
import headerTopBar from "~/components/header/headerTopBar.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    promo,
    headerTopBar
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <header>
    <div class="header-outer">
      <div class="header-inner">
        <header-top-bar />
        <promo />
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

`

`

Comment: нужно было прописать в консоли yarn add --save-dev node-sass sass-loader